# How many combinations are there to pull at least 1 ace with 10 cards.

Tags: combinatorics

We have deck of cards (52 cards). 10 random cards will be picked. How many chances are there, that **atleast** 1 of the random cards is "ace".

At first I tried to calculate how many different possibilities are there to pull 10 random cards without any extra conditions.
According to formula nCk= n! / k!(n-k)!:
I got 52! / 10! * 42!

Next I tried to calculate how many possibilities are to pull 10 cards from deck, that does not contain any "aces"
I got 48! / 10! * 38!

Then I could subtract second answer from first and I would be left over with answer. Since the numbers are too huge to try on calculator, I wondered if my solutions works.

Comment: The logic looks good.  Note:  since you are interested in the ratio, there is a great deal of cancellation.  There's no need to compute either binomial coefficient explicitly.

Comment: As a different approach:  the probability that the first is not an ace is $\frac {48}{52}$.  Conditioned on that, the probability that the second is also not an ace is $\frac {47}{51}$.  And so on.

Comment: @lulu wait. As I understand you are answering, what is probability to get an ace. I need to know how many different combinations are there, that contain ace.

Comment: I understood "how many chances" to mean "what's the probability".  If you just meant the number of combinations, then you can use the binomial symbol approach or you can multiply my expression by the number of unrestricted combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to give the answer as:

${52\choose 10} - {48\choose 10}$

That *is* an acceptable answer but if you want to caluculate it it is.

$\frac {52!}{42!10!} - \frac {48!}{38!10!} =$

$\frac {48!}{38!10!}(\frac {52*51*50*49}{42*41*40*39} - 1)=$

$\frac {39*....*48}{10!}(\frac {52*51*50*49}{42*41*40*39}-\frac {42*41*40*39}{42*41*40*39})=$

$\frac {43*44*....*48}{10!}(52*51*50*49 - 42*41*40*39)=$

.... factor terms out.

$\frac {(43*22*1*46*47*1)*6*8*9*10}{10!}(13*17*5*7 - 1*41*2*39)2*3*4*5*7=$

$(43*22*46*47)(13*17*5*7 - 41*2*39)$

And that *can* be plugged into a calculator.

But.... 1)  NOBODY CARES!!!!  The answer ${52\choose 10} - {48\choose 10}$ is good enough and

2) If you have a computer it comes with a calculator and the numbers *aren't* too high

$52! = 8.0658175170943878571660636856404e+67$

$\frac {52!}{42!} = 57407703889536000$

$\frac {52!}{42!10!} = 15820024220$

$48! = 1.2413915592536072670862289047373e+61$

$\frac {48!}{38!10!} = 6540715896$

and $\frac {52!}{42!10!} - \frac {48}{38!10!} = 9279308324$

.... which.... nobody cares.  Unless you are doing probability ... in which case $\frac {{52\choose 10} - {48 \choose 10}}{52\choose 10}$ is easy to calculate with cancelation as $1 -\frac {48!42!}{52!38!}= 1- \frac {39*40*41*42}{49*50*51*52} = 1- \frac{41*6}{7*5*17}$