# From a deck of 52 cards, extract 10. In how many combinations do you get at least one ace?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If from a deck of 52 cards, I extract 10. In how many combinations do you get at least one ace?

I have come up with two possible answers, but I don't know which one is the right one and why.

So one is $$4{51 \choose 9}$$ 
the reasoning is that first I extract an ace from the four that there are, and then I have ${51 \choose 9}$ combinations for the other 9 cards.

The second is 
$${52 \choose 10} - {48 \choose 10}$$  reasoning that there are ${52 \choose 10}$ total combinations of ten cards and I subtract ${48 \choose 10}$ combinations without any aces.

So from other questions it seems that the first one is the correct answer, but why would the second one be wrong?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Your first method counts hands with more than one ace multiple times.

Comment: @lulu  That's important as a point, but the question wants to count all hands with *at least one ace*.  There is still overcounting going on though.

Comment: @amWhy lulu is pointing out that certain *hands* are counted too many times.

Comment: I said as much, @Théophile

Comment: The second method is correct.  It is the best way for the general question. - to obtain probability of at least one, calculate the probability of none and subtract from $1$.

Comment: @amWhy Not sure I see your point.  if $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^8$ denote specific non-aces, then the OP's method counts $A\spadesuit, A\heartsuit, \{X_i\}_{i=1}^8$ as one case, and the equivalent reordered hand $A\heartsuit, A\spadesuit, \{X_i\}_{i=1}^8$ as another.  I understand the OP is counting hands containing  at least one ace.

Comment: This same question was asked yesterday: [How many combinations are there to pull at least 1 ace with 10 cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013275/how-many-combinations-are-there-to-pull-at-least-1-ace-with-10-cards?rq=1). @lulu You should have recognized it, as you commented on it.

Answer (score 2):

The first approach needs to be modified to ${4\choose1}{48\choose 9}+{4\choose2}{48\choose 8}+{4\choose 3}{48\choose 7}+{4\choose 4}{48\choose 6}$, for instance.

The second is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To see why your first answer is not correct, assume you have a deck of 3 with 2 aces and you'll draw 2 cards with at least one ace.  Call the cards $A_1,A_2,B$

Based on your logic, you compute $2 {2 \choose 1}=4$ combinations.  However, clearly you have only $3$.  This is due to double counting $\{A_1,A_2\}$